# Authorization node.js by domino

Tags: node.js, authorization, lotus-domino

From domono http sessoin to node.js server

In my application (chat) l use node.js + socket.io

node.js http by socket.io send/receive messages for chat but have not restrict access

Any nonauthorized user can send message like anonymous. it's problem.

1)
How to make, that only user authorized in domino http session can use node.js http server ?

2) 
Method 2: node.js by using js script + socket.io can check by 'socket.io sessoin id' and   in "domino cache document user" which created when authorised user open domino page and call domino script to set in this document  field username + sessoin id. 
(If  "cache document user" have not socket.io sessoin id then socket.io ignore anonymous user.)

Which method better for secure?
How simple realize 1) method?

Comment: This question could be improved with more details.  For example, what language are you using to send the HTTP request from Domino to the Node.js server?  Java or LotusScript?  Also, does your Node.js server care about the identity of the Domino user, or are you just trying to prevent access from anonymous users?  If it's the latter, you could configure client certificate HTTPS on the Node.js side.  That way a client would have to present a certificate to make a connection.